# Regex for removing empty tags or with only spaces/tabs in it

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Sorry for initial post, was sent to early... Here again:

Im looking for a regex in Javascript replacing the p-tag with empty or with any spaces or tabs filled in it by '', like:

```
<p></p>
```

or

```
<p>      </p>
```

If there are any other signs than space(s) and tab(s) between the tag then the complete tag with its content should be untouched (NOT replaced by '') like:

```
<p>    A  </p>
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
myString.replace( new RegExp( "<p>[\s]+</p>", "g" ), "" );
```

Comment: This almost literally jumps out from multiple examples talking about the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  Don't use Regex to parse HTML, use an HTML parser.  There are plenty of options available:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers

Comment: no, my comment was definitely made after your edits.  This **is not** something to use Regex for.  If you are trying to clean up HTML code (removing empty tags is a form of cleanup), there are multiple HTML parsers that do this.  They do not use Regex (normally), and there are so many edge cases surrounding HTML in general that it's pointless to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It is ridiculous to attach a HTML parser for just this simple text operation task that could be easily done by a regex (Javascript builtin functionality). I was asking for a regex not for tools doing this job, thanks anyway.

Comment: try `<p>[\s]*</p>`,  https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=99282

Comment: @ Jonny how do you intend to make sure you avoid deleting preformatted elements who's empty spaces are structural and of the same importance as any other html tag using the regex lol?

Comment: Good question! I didn't want to go too far explaining everything: I'm reading from an HTML editor thats output I've checked in many ways. In the end I can ensure that <p></p> or <p>    <p> elements are obsolete and can be removed. If the user enters manually a space it will look like <p>&nbsp;</p>, that I want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google will show you a ton of posts explaining why regex and HTML do not mix. You can quite easily find empty elements and then do what you like with them by searching the DOM like normal.

```
var tags_i_want = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(i = 0; i < tags_i_want.length; i++) {
    if(tags_i_want[i].innerHTML.trim() == '') {
        // Do whatever you need to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is some JavaScript Voodoo Parts, for you to try:*

```js
function delEmptyTags( x ) {
   var e = document.getElementsByTagName(x),a = [].slice.call(e), i;
                                      console.log( "paragraphs total: " + e.length );
        while( a[0] ) i = a.pop(),
            !i.innerText ? i.outerHTML = '' : 0;
                                      console.log( "paragraphs left: " + e.length );
};


Execute: delEmptyTags( "p" );
```

```html
<p> P has text 1
<p>         <!-- has empty spaces -->
<p>   <!-- has tabs -->
<p>

<!-- has new lines -->

<p> P has text 2
```

Comment: and it comes with an additional Voodoo benefit, which you can never achieve automatically using straightforward regex routine, that is: *avoid deleting tags with empty spaces contained on pre-formatted elements* and make a rendering mess out of its content.